# Who provides the Audio and Video Codec support in case of HTML5 player?

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio

When a video is played on a browser, which supports HTML5, who is actually providing the codec support? Is it the browser or the OS? And how can I find the list of codecs supported?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way to query this, but there are known formats browsers sorry by default. Unfortunately I don't think there's any format supported by all browsers by default, si you'd have to provide multiple formats at the same time.

As for the actual codec, that's completely up to the browser. They can bring their own code or reuse some provided by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to audio playing, if you use `<audio>` tag, it means the browser uses embedded codecs. List of supported codecs you can see on [Media formats supported by the HTML audio and video elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

If you want to use other codecs you should use the `<embed>` or `<object>` tags